# How can I return matching query from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, object

I have an array of JSON objects to be output, where if the user enters an input the system will return the matching records, looking at **name, mobileNumber, hobbies and gender**.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="query" @input="getUserInput.get">
      // where i output the people data
    <app-people v-bind:people="people"></app-people>
  </div>
</template>
```

I store the function to get user data in computed property and fetch it using `@input="getUserInput.get"` which is on input element above.

```
  computed: {
    getUserInput: {
      get: function () {
        return this.people.filter((person) => (
          person.name.includes(this.query) ||
          person.gender.includes(this.query) ||
          person.mobileNumber.filter((number) => (
            number.includes(this.query)
          )) ||
          person.hobbies.filter((hobby) => (
            hobby.includes(this.query)
          ))
        ))
      }
    }
  }
```

My people data looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
          "mobileNumber": [
              "011324567"
          ],
          "hobbies": [
              "running",
              "sleeping",
              "hiking",
          ],
          "name": "Ahmad Ali",
          "gender": "male",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
          "mobileNumber": [
              "123123333",
              "26371830"
          ],
          "hobbies": [
              "coding"
          ],
          "name": "Maria",
          "gender": "female",
    }
  ]
```

The people data is returning fine however when inputting query, the result won't change. Is there anything wrong with my code, particularly the `getUserInput.get` function? And is there any other ways to improve my code? Since this code below:

```
        return this.people.filter((person) => (
          person.name.includes(this.query) ||
          person.gender.includes(this.query) ||
          person.mobileNumber.filter((number) => (
            number.includes(this.query)
          )) ||
          person.hobbies.filter((hobby) => (
            hobby.includes(this.query)
          ))
        ))
```

is not clean at all. Thank you!

Comment: inside filter, should it be `||` instead of `,`?

Comment: ` ===` will look for exact match, you should use `includes` or `srartsWith` as per your need

Comment: @AkhilAravind i edited my code as per your answer however it is still not returning the updated queries. it feels like something's wrong with the whole function eventhough it does get fired

Comment: could you mind checking the fiddle
`https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3edjsg?file=src%2FApp.vue`

Comment: full code can be seen at `https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3edjsg?file=src%2FApp.vue`

Comment: At first glance, my sophisticated guess is ... both `person.mobileNumber.filter` and `person.hobbies.filter` should not use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method but [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), hence ... `person.mobileNumber.some( ... )` respectively `person.hobbies.some( ... )`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
return this.people.filter((person) => (
      person.name.includes(this.query) ||
      person.gender.includes(this.query) ||
      person.mobileNumber.filter((number) => (
        number.includes(this.query)
      )).length > 0 ||
      person.hobbies.filter((hobby) => (
        hobby.includes(this.query)
      )).length > 0
    ))
```

Sorry I can’t test it now, since I’m not on my computer. Hope this helps..